# Convert two 32 bit floats to one 64 bit number and vice versa

Tags: c, floating-point, 64-bit, 32bit-64bit, type-conversion

I need to convert two 32 bit floats into one 64 bit number and vice versa in C.
What's the best way of achieving this?

I am a little confused as to the best way and if I should convert from a float in 32 bit to a long in 64 bit and vice versa.

Help appreciated.

Comment: It depends on how the "two 32 bit floats" are related:  are they two independent values?  Or is a 64 bit value split up among them?

Comment: Do you want to store the two 32 bit floats in one 64 bit double?

Comment: What *kind* of 64 bit number do you want to convert them to? And why?

Comment: "Convert two 32 bit floats into one 64 bit number" does not make sense without further explanation. What kind of conversion is meant here?

Answer (score 4):

If you're talking about combining them mathematically somehow (such as addition), you can just coerce them both to 64-bit first:

```
float pi = 3.141592653589;
float e  = 2.718281828459;
double sum = (double)pi + (double)e;
```

I'm guessing that's *not* what you want since, as someone pointed out in the comments, it would be hard to get back to the original values if all you have is the sum of them.

---

If you're talking simply combining the bits sequentially, you can do something like:

```
#include <stdio.h>

union {
    struct {
        float f1;
        float f2;
    };
    double d;
} xyzzy;

int main (void) {
    xyzzy.f1 = 3.141592653589;
    xyzzy.f2 = 2.718281828459;
    double d2 = xyzzy.d;

    printf ("%lf\n", xyzzy.d);

    xyzzy.f1 = 0;
    xyzzy.f2 = 0;
    xyzzy.d = d2;

    printf ("%f %f\n", xyzzy.f1, xyzzy.f2);
}
```

which outputs:

```
14.985018
3.141593 2.718282
```

although you should keep in mind that such behaviour (type punning) is implementation defined as to whether it'll work. In any case, if the `float` values are 32-bit size and alignment, the inner `struct` itself will almost certainly be 64-bit and you can use that instead of the `double` (in other words, use the `struct` and get rid of the enclosing `union`).

If you want some functions that'll do the grunt work for you, see below:

```
#include <stdio.h>

double cvtToDbl (float n1, float n2) {
    struct { float n1; float n2; } s;
    s.n1 = n1;
    s.n2 = n2;
    return *((double*)&s);
}

void cvtToFlts (double d, float *pn1, float *pn2) {
    struct { float n1; float n2; } *ps = (void*)&d;
    *pn1 = ps->n1;
    *pn2 = ps->n2;
}

int main (void) {
    float f1 = 0, f2 = 0;
    double d = cvtToDbl (3.141592653589, 2.718281828459);
    printf ("%lf\n", d);

    cvtToFlts (d, &f1, &f2);
    printf ("%f %f\n", f1, f2);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The OP said they want to be able to revert from the "*64 bit number*" to the 32 bit floats. This is not possible with the first solution (add). I guess what they want is something like your solution #2.

Comment: @ArjunShankar: good point, I didn't actually notice that in the question. Adjusted answer to clarify.